# IE11 & 2012R2 History GPO

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, internet-explorer

probably a really simple one but I've not been able to find it.

I am running a 2012R2/Win 8.1 environment and want to stop IE from storing any browsing history on a machine level.

I've already set IE to apply settings per machine rather an per user but can't fins the setting to stop IE storing any browsing history.

A lot of googling gives me dozens of ways to stop users deleting their browsing history - but I'm looking to not store it to begin with!

These machines will be on 24-7 with a logged in user, so a delete on exit policy doesn't cut it :(

Am happy to launch IE at initial logon with a switch to stop browsing history.

Any thoughts?

Ben

Comment: browsing history isn't per machine, but per user profile.  If you are wanting to setup an "internet kiosk" type solution there are 3rd party tools out there that will do what you are asking here.

Comment: Not quite Internet Kiosk... but several thousand PCs spread across dozens of locations - all autologon with a user account per location and each machine used by several people.  Some 3rd party apps we use are rubbish and you can re-launch into someone else's "session" with a simple shuffle through the machines browser history

Comment: OK, to your last point about a switch, the only thing I can think of there would be to change/set their IE shortcuts to use `-private` and force each session to open In Private Browsing instead.  This might not work though if the 3rd party browser apps require tracking/cookies etc.

Comment: -private will work.. I was just wondering whether there was a more elegant solution.  Thankfully, an IE process is started at logon and all sites/visits spawn from this parent process.. just wondered for the most part if I'd missed the wood for the trees.